# How can I theme my Ionic 3 app with linear gradient color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

```
$color {
  primary : linear-gradient(160deg, #aa7ecd, #02ccba);
 }
```

Gives erro as - The map color `primary` is not defined. Please make sure the color exists in your `$colors` map. For example: $colors: ( primary: #327eff );